# Dataset sorting and add data in machine learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning, dataset

Got a dataset of ID (auto increment) and a random number sequence.

ID,Rnumber
1,500
2,799
3,683
4,237
5,974
6,654
7,778
8,423
9,389

And im trying to create a rank from highest to smallest value and categorize sequences of the dataset based on the rank in groups.

Example: Rank 1-150 is placed in groupe 1
Rank 151-300 is placed in groupe 2 and so on.

What is the easiest solution to this using azure machine learning?

I realize that this may be easy, but since my knowledge on this subject is limited to a general knowledge of function and usage its still alot of possibilities and functions to explore machine learning.

So since i got this specific question im asking it here to get a boosted start!

Any help appriciated!

Comment: you should add #azure or #azureML tag to this question.

Comment: I believe that the feature you seek is "binning".  Look for the ability to specify the width of each bin.  I found a starting point [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-data-science-create-features-sql-server/#sql-binningfeature)